# URL Hack is not passing Record Type across correctly

Tags: urlhacking

I have a Custom Button in Salesforce that uses a URL hack to pass a couple of parameters across. This button is launched from the Opportunity Page, and refers to a Custom Object called 'Cross Sell'. When this button is clicked, I need to go to the Record Type Selection Page (for Cross Sell) and then upon picking the desired Record Type, for a number of these parameters to pass across.  Most of this is working fine, however I find when I pick a Record Type and select it, it reverts back to the Default Record Type for Cross Sell. Not sure why this is happening (I've checked my workflows and can't see a reason for this). The URL hack is below. Any help would be much appreciated:

```
/setup/ui/recordtypeselect.jsp?ent=01Id0000000raEp&retURL=%2Fa0E%2Fo&save_new_url=%2Fa0E%2Fe%3FCF00Nd0000007ae22={!Opportunity.Name}%26CF00Nd0000007ae22_lkid={!Opportunity.Id}%26CF00Nd0000007ae1t={!Account.Name}%26CF00Nd0000007ae1t_lkid={!Account.Id}%2600Nd0000007ae1v={!URLENCODE(Opportunity.Opportunity_Notes__c)}%26CF01Id0000000raEp={!Account.Name}
```

Comment: So you get taken to the edit page appropriately? Is there any code that works on this object that could be setting the record type?

Comment: Hi Eric, thats correct. I get to the edit page fine, and most of the parameters pass across correctly. This is a new Custom Object so there's no code yet that could be setting the Record type.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this hack for one of my implementation and it worked like a charm. I suspect one of 3 things :

1. A workflow rule 
2. An Apex Trigger
3. Other record types not accessible on profile.

[image: Profile View]
 OR

[image: Enhanced Profile View]

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your answer. I've re-checked the user profiles and the workflow rules. All profiles have access to all Record Types and there are no Record Name field updates for this Object. I'm also not a coder, so there's no Apex Triggers for the Cross Sell Object. I've noticed this issue only occurs for some Users and not others (people on the same profiles)

Comment: Could it be url encoding/browser based ?